# Can we cover a self similar set using another self similar set with smaller dimension?

Tags: real-analysis, fractal-analysis

Suppose we have two self similar sets $A$ and $B$ constructed as follows:

Let $\varphi_i(x):=\frac{x+i}{5},i=0,1,2,3,4$ be similarities, then $A$ and $B$ are self similar sets with:

$$A=\varphi_0(A)\cup\varphi_2(A)\cup\varphi_4(A)\text{ and }B=\varphi_1(A)\cup\varphi_3(A).$$
Can we cover $A$ with countably many translates of the set $B$?

I believe not, but I am stuck on one small implication.

My attempt:

Using the open set condition on $(0,1)$ we can easily calculate the dimension of $A$ and $B$ using Morans Theorem and show that $\dim_H(B)<\dim_H(A).$
Since a translation is a bi-Lipshitz map, it preserves the Hausdorff dimension (informally, moving $B$ doesn't change its Hausdorff dimension). Also, the dimension of a countable union of sets is the supremum of the dimension of sets, hence any countable union of translations of $B$ have dimension $\dim_H(B)$ which is strictly less than $\dim_H(A)$.

So finally, can I conclude that if the dimension of countably many translations of $B$ is still less than the dimension of $A$, we can never cover it this way?

Comment: The Hausdorff dimension is monotonic:  if $A \subseteq B$, then $\dim_{H}(A) \le \dim_{H}(B)$.  What does this tell you about your question?

Comment: Oh I see, then it follows that $\dim_H(B)<\dim_H(A)$ which implies $B\subset{}A.$

Comment: No, that isn't quite right.  You can have $\dim_H(B) < \dim_H(A)$ without $B \subsetneq A$.  But *if* $B \subseteq A$, *then* $\dim_H(B) \le \dim_H(A)$.  In your case, you know that $$ \dim_H \left( \bigcup_{j} \tau_j B \right) < \dim_H(A),$$ (where each $\tau_j$ is a translation indexed over some countable set) which implies that it cannot be the case that $A \subseteq B$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Hausdorff dimension has the following relevant properties:

1. **Countable stability:** Let $\{ E_j \}_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a countable collection of sets.  Then
   $$ \dim_H\left( \bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}} E_j \right) \le \sup_{j\in\mathbb{N}} \dim_{H}(E_j).$$
2. **Monotonicity:** If $E \subseteq F$, then $\dim_H(E) \subseteq \dim_H(F)$.

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary subsets of some Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$ \dim_{H}(B) < \dim_H(A). $$
Assume for contradiction that there exists a countable collection of translations $\{\tau_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that
$$ A \subseteq \bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}} \tau_j B.$$
That is, assume that $A$ may be covered by a countable number of copies of $B$.  Translation is an isometry, hence it preserves the Hausdorff dimension.  Thus $\dim_{H}( \tau_j B) = \dim_H(B)$ for all $j$.  The Haudsorff dimension is countably stable and monotonic, thus
$$ \dim_{H}(A)
\le \dim_{H}\left( \bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}} \tau_j B\right)
\le \sup_{j\in\mathbb{N}} \dim_{H}(\tau_j B)
= \dim_{H} (B)
< \dim_{H}(A),$$
which is a contradiction.